# About deferred execution of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, deferred-execution

In the following code, I understand the second initialization prints one "outside" and three "inside".  But why does the first does not print at all, I expect it to print one "outside".

```
        DeferExecution a = new DeferExecution(); // prints nothing 
        DeferExecution b = new DeferExecution(null); // print one "outside" and three "inside".

 class DeferExecution
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Input;

    public DeferExecution()
    {
        Input = GetIEnumerable();
    }

    public DeferExecution(string intput)
    {
        Input = GetIEnumerable().ToArray();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetIEnumerable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("outside");  
        var strings = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside");  
            yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The enumerable returned is implemented as an [iterator block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) (i.e., a method that uses `yield`).

Code inside iterator blocks does not actually execute until they are enumerated for the first time, so you won't see anything happen if you don't actually do anything with the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Note that it is `ToArray()` which iterates over the enumerable, as it needs to retrieve all values to construct the array.

Comment: yes, but Console.WriteLine("outside") is outside the iterator block. why it is not print either.

Comment: @hongpei: The iterator block is what the whole method is called. Once it starts running it continues until it hits `yield`. You propose that it should start running immediately and stop... where? and why?

Comment: I was kind of thinking the iterator block should be the area between the first yield and the last yield.

Comment: but my above thought would make it impossible to define iterator block, isnt it?

Comment: As an aside, if you call `Input = GetIEnumerable().Any()`, it should print one Outside and one Inside, as it iterates once and then stops when it sees a result.  The `ToArray()` will iterate until the end.

Since the constructor without any parameters doesn't use `ToArray()`, the variable `Input` is only holding onto a promise to create a collection of strings when they're needed.

Comment: @hongpei: It would make it awkward. Anyway, you may want to think about the difference between `{ yield return 42; }` and `{ return Enumerable.Repeat(42, 1); }`. The second is implemented in terms of the first, and while enumerating them will give the same results  these two method bodies are quite different.